# How can I get it so that it tells the user they used the incorrect type of input once and then prompts them to pledge their bet amount again?

Tags: python, while-loop

I want the program to tell the user that they need their input to be a whole number only but only once, and then afterwards prompt them to input how much they would like to bet. The break is there because I had the problem of it outputting the print statement infinitely.

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/UseEX.png)
[The code I have currently]

Tried to use a for loop to no success also

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: That first duplicate question should answer your question. Let me point out a few more things about your code. The `input` function will always return a string, so checking if it is an integer or not won't work. Otherwise, the normal way of checking if a variable is an integer or not would be by doing `isinstance(some_variable, int)`.  Lastly, continue brings you back to the beginning of the loop, so if your code did work the way you expected it to, if an int was entered, you would keep getting brought back to the beginning of the while loop, and you would have an infinite loop.